# Prevent group to create but not inherited groups Odoo

Tags: xml, security, odoo, odoo-11, access-rights

i have 4 groups in attendance model i want to prevent 'base.group_user' to create new records so i add access right:

```
**hr_attendance.access_hr_attendance_system_user,hr.attendance.system.user,hr_attendance.model_hr_attendance,base.group_user,1,0,0,0**
```

but when i used kiosk mode (in Attendance) i can't create new records by other groups (these groups inherit 'base.group_user') .. so i added access right to other groups to create but it still not working.
**my user in Lirten Attendance/Receptionist Group but can't create by kiosk in attendance**

[image: my user in Lirten Attendance/Receptionist Group but can't create by kiosk in attendance]

Comment: Your approach seems right, but why is the user (ID 9) not in one of the groups with the create right?